# [solved]:-How to publish negative values from command line?

Tags: rosserial, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try this command.i got an error like this.How can i  publish negative values from command line ?

```
rostopic pub servo std_msgs/UInt16 -180

Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

rostopic: error: no such option: -8
```

this is my code:-

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
signed int angle;
const int stepPin = 9; 
const int dirPin = 8;
int x;

ros::NodeHandle  nh;
void pwm( const std_msgs::UInt16& cmd_msg)
{
  
angle=cmd_msg.data;
//angle=map(angle,280,1720,-720,720);
 
 if (angle<0)
 {
 cw();
 delay(100);
 }
 
 else
 {
 ccw();
 delay(100);
 }
 
      
}


ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::UInt16> sub("servo", pwm);

void setup(){
 // pinMode(angle, OUTPUT); 
   
 pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
  
 // servo.attach(9); //attach it to pin 9
}

void loop()
{
   
  
nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
void cw()
{
  digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW); 
  for(x = 0; x < 17.77*(angle*-1); x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
  }}
  void ccw()
{
  digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH); 
  for(x = 0; x < 17.77*angle; x++) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
    digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(500); 
  }}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279547/%5Bsolved%5D:-how-to-publish-negative-values-from-command-line-?/) by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-11**:
The answers are correct saying that a negative value for a `Uint` is wrong but they don't give much explanation. Here's why: the `U` in `Uint` is for unsigned meaning *not negative*. `Uint`s by definition *cannot be negative*.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-12**:
If you need a signed integer use `Int16` instead of `UInt16`

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2018-01-12**:
FYI, if you need to know what's in a given message, check out its source:

http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int16.html

You can see that the field you need to fill out is called 'data', as others have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two issues:

1. The command should be:  `rostopic pub servo std_msgs/UInt16 "data: 180"`. You have to specify what the fields of the message have. The `-180` is intrepreted as command line Options (and rightly so). Just hit Tab after you add the type, and the fields appear automatically.
2. Putting a negative value in an **unsigned** type is just wrong and will throw another error.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-01-12**:
i updated my question.can you check my code ?
i need signed integer input.(stepper motor angle).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-12**:
Well, I'm not quite sure what your question is. If you want to use signed data types (i.e. negative values as well), just replace every occurence of `UInt16` with `Int16`.

If you don't know the difference, maybe read around a bit on Google about signed/unsigned types...

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-01-12**:
@mig i replace UInt16 with Int16. and try this

```
rostopic pub servo std_msgs/Int16 -360
Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

rostopic: error: no such option: -3
```

How to publish Negative values in Int16 ?. cammand for that ?

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-01-12**:
Thank you so much. @mig

```
rostopic pub servo std_msgs/Int16 "data: -720"
```

this works.thanx to all

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use TAB for autocomplete
rostopic pub /servo std_msgs/UInt16 "data: 0"

UInt16 is **unsigned** type of data

---

Originally posted by [0xd1ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27403/0xd1ma/) with karma: 92 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-01-12**:
i updated my question.can you check my code ?
i need signed integer input.(stepper motor angle).

**Comment by [sudo_melvinyesudas](https://answers.ros.org/users/33001/sudo_melvinyesudas/) on 2018-01-12**:
thanx.it works.